# SAML in http request, How to get Saml form request?

Tags: asp.net-core, saml

I have an `asp.net core` site that receives incoming traffic form a small sign portal. User goes to portal. Portal redirects them to my site on successful login. I can not figure out how to get the `saml token` or any information. I have to validate the token and get the `userid`. Can someone point me in the right direction? I am not sending a request, they are coming to my site with a token in hand.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You won't f do much without an external framework. Not sure if net core already had a working saml2 middleware though.

Comment: I strongly recommend using an existing framework so you get the security right. You'll find open-source and commercial packages available on www.nuget.org. Just search for SAML.

Comment: Agreed - don't roll your own, Use an existing SAML client-side stack - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43